# How to generate lines of code automatically in python scripts

Tags: python, if-statement

I have `python` file called `test.py`. In this file I will execute some `pyspark` commands.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext

conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

# create a data frame from hive tables
df=sqlContext.table("testing.test")

# register the data frame as temp table
df.registerTempTable('mytempTable')

# find number of records in data frame
records = df.count()

print "records='%s'" %records


if records < 1000000:
 sqlContext.sql("create table {}.{} stored as parquet as select * from mytempTable".format(hivedb,table))
else:
 sqlContext.sql("create table {}.{} stored as parquet as select * from mytempTable where id <= 1000000".format(hivedb,table))
 sqlContext.sql("insert into table {}.{} select * from mytempTable where id > 1000000 and id <= 2000000".format(hivedb,table))
 sqlContext.sql("insert into table {}.{} select * from mytempTable where id > 2000000 and id <= 3000000".format(hivedb,table))
 sqlContext.sql("insert into table {}.{} select * from mytempTable where id > 3000000 and id <= 4000000".format(hivedb,table))
 sqlContext.sql("insert into table {}.{} select * from mytempTable where id > 4000000 and id <= 5000000".format(hivedb,table))
 and so on till the last million
```

In the `if-else` statement after `else` The code I have written manually.

I want to generate this part of code in the script automatically.

How to generate similar lines of code until the last million in `records`?

Comment: Do you know how to create a loop?

Comment: What does the `where` clause do in an `insert` statement?

Comment: @Intrested_user That is what you need. Read up on "Python for loop" and "Python range", then incorporate them into your question.

Comment: Notice that `range(10, 10, 10)` won't produce any value / the `for` loop won't run. Please, change into `range(10, 100, 10)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple loop:

```
fmt = "insert into table {hivedb}.{table} select * from mytempTable where id > {low} and id <= {hi}"
for low in range(100000, 1000000, 100000):
    stmt = fmt.format(low=low, hi=low+100000, hivedb=hivedb, table=table)
    sqlContext.sql(stmt)
```

Comment: The TableNotFoundException is another problem. This exception should have already raised before changing your code with a loop.